# How to combine service discovery and read characteristic using RxAndroidBle

Tags: android, rx-java, rxandroidble

I'm new to Rx programming. I'm now trying to use `RxAndroidBle` to discover BLE devices' services and read some characteristics from the device.

I can use

```
device.establishConnection(false)
  .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.discoverServices());
```

to find device services

and use

```
device.establishConnection(false)
  .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(characteristicUUID));
```

to read wanted characteristic

But I'd like to know if it is possible to combine these two tasks together? If possible, how can I do it?

Many thanks for your tips and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're using a helper method `readCharacteristic(UUID)`. You can skip the discovery at all and the library will do it for you under the hood seamlessly.

Sure, just use flatMap with zip or publish with merge. There are many ways but this one is a basic and silly one.

```
 bleDevice
     .establishConnection(false)
     .flatMap(connection ->
         Observable.zip(
             connection.readCharacteristic(UUID.randomUUID()).doOnNext(data -> doSomethingWithData(data)),
             connection.discoverServices().doOnNext(services -> doSomethingWithServices(data)),
             Pair::create
         )
      )
      .subscribe();
```

It'd be best if you could do some RxJava training.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but I also want to discover services, not just read characteristics, is there any way to realize this?

Comment: Many thanks for you kindly help and suggestion! This helps to make it work! It's necessary for me do more training on RxJava

Comment: by using establishConnection and then to discover service, I found that sometimes, it never goes to discover service, and the subscriber's onError onCompleted will never happen, it seems that the connection was not established and the process will be stuck for a period. I'm wondering if there is a way to limit the time for establishing  connection? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't find Pair in RxJAVA package. How to import ?

Comment: Have a look in Android Support package.